# How to access a docker container with an Angular app also running in a Container?

Tags: angular, docker, docker-compose

I have an app which consists of a frontend and a backend. Both should run together in a container in a Docker compose. The backend works fine and has not caused any problems while developing the frontend.
Now we come to the frontend. The frontend is an Angular app which uses Angular routing. While developing I always developed with "ng serve" and used the following proxy-conf.json to access the API:

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:3000",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

However, now I want to run my frontend in a container as well. For this I have dockerized the Angular app with the following Dockerfile. I can access the App, but every API-Call does not work.

```
FROM node:16-alpine AS build

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN npm install

RUN npm run build

# Serve Application using Nginx Server

FROM nginx:alpine

COPY --from=build /app/dist/my-app/ /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

EXPOSE 80
```

This is my nginx.conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

My docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
   
  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./frontend/my-app
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    depends_on:
      - backend
```

I have read many stackoverflow articles,however,nonew ar purposeful.  How can I access the backend from my app?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Since the Angular application runs in a browser, it's not in a container (and maybe not even on the same machine) and can't use any of the Docker networking features.  You need to connect to the host system's DNS name or IP address (or `localhost` if you know the browser and containers are on the same system) and the first `ports:` number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add a **proxy_pass** on nginx.conf like this:

```
location /api/ {
       proxy_pass          ${API_HOST};
       proxy_http_version  1.1;
       proxy_set_header    Upgrade $http_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header    Connection keep-alive;
       proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;    
       proxy_cache_bypass  $http_upgrade;
       proxy_pass_request_headers on;
    }
```

I think on your dev environment you call an API like this `http://localhost:3000/api`.

Adding this location on nginx.conf tell to the server: *"when coming a request on http://localhost:3000/api/ then redirect it to ${API_HOST}"*

The ${API_HOST} must set to the backend, in this case, is `http://backend:3000/` the API suffix is added by the location.

The other settings basically add to the headers the infos about the original request.